# Can't retrieve session in Laravel Blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-session

I set up a controller to pass errors if validation fails and another message if passed it.

```php
if ($v->fails()) {
    return redirect('tickets/create')->withInput()->withErrors($v->errors());
} else {
    $ticket_id = $this->salvataggio($request);
    
    return redirect('tickets/' . $ticket_id . '/edit')
        ->with(['status' => 'success']);
}
```

In the blade file of the view, I can read the error variable but I can't read the status.

```
@if(Session::has('status'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('status')}}</div>
@endif
```

I have read and tried many methods to retrieve Session but it seems doesn't work. I've already used this method on a previous project with Laravel 5 but in this version (8.11.0), has something has changed?

Comment: in what blade file do you have this check to see if you have the session variable named 'status'?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the session first...

```php
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('status', 'success');

// Via the global helper...
session(['status' => 'success']);
```

And then you can retrieve the session data...

```php
// Via a request instance...
$value = $request->session()->get('status');

// Via the global helper...
$value = session(['status']);

// In blade...
{{session('status')}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You used the `with` method so you should change your code like below:

```
@if($status)
   <div class="alert alert-success">{{$status}}</div>
@endif
```